# What is the QueryParser's syntax for proximity search?

Tags: lucene, information-retrieval, query-parser

I have been trying to implement proximity search using **Lucene 3.6**. I went for `SpanNearQuery` which almost did the trick for me, but my teacher says `QueryParser` can do it in a much nicer way (it would also filter the query using the analyzer, unlike `SpanNearQuery`). Can anyone tell me the syntax of the query? I've been searching on the internet for last few hours now. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at [Lucene query syntax documentation](http://lucene.apache.org/core/3_6_0/queryparsersyntax.html#Proximity%20Searches)?

Comment: Yes I did, but it did not work for me, more likely I was making some mistake. Here's what I did: `QueryParser queryParser= new QueryParser(Version.LUCENE_36, "myField", analyzer);
Query query= queryParser.parse("word1 word2 ~1");`
It gives error on runtime saying something about fuzzy search. But if I put the "~1" after the string, my Eclipse gives syntax error. Can you please help me with the syntax?

Comment: You need to add quotes to your query string. The quotes you wrote just make Java understand that you are writing a String litteral, but it will read it as `word1 word2 ~1` (without quotes), you need to write `queryParser.parse("\"word1 word2\"~1")` (the backslashes are for escaping so that Java doesn't interpret them as the end of the String

Comment: Thank you. It works. Btw, doesn't it work more like a 'biword index'? I take two terms and mention their maximum distance allowed and take AND with other terms. I appreciate you response. :)

Comment: I came up with the way to make my tri-word, quad-word query work as well. It was simple. The query string is like this `"\"word1 word2\"~1 AND \"word3\"~0 AND \"word4\"~0"`. It might help somebody in the future. :)